# HTML homework created with pandoc from LaTeX includes the answers. Oops

Tags: latex, pandoc, pdflatex

I have a fairly large number (dozens) of homeworks written in LaTeX that I compile to PDF. We have recently adopted a LMS (Canvas) that needs HTML files. Conversion to HTML is easy peasy with pandoc, using the following command.

```
pandoc -s core3-hw08.tex  --mathjax -c test.css -o core3hw08.html
```

Unfortunately, I included the homework answers following \end{document} in the tex files. This works great with PDF because my command (*pdflatex*) ignores everything after the end of the document. Pandoc doesn't, and the result is that the homework answers are converted to HTML along with the homework questions. Oops.

I could create an entire additional set of homework tex files without the answers, but that seems a bad solution --- having two identical sets of files with the only difference that one set as the answers and the other doesn't.  I also want to keep the answers and questions in the same source document.

Is there any way to tell pandoc to ignore everything after \end{document}? I don't mind revising the source documents, which can be done with a script.

Comment: have you tried with the newest pandoc version?

Comment: Yes, thank you. The newest version (2.10.1) did exactly what I expected. Thank you.